# Using sed to replace multiple lines in multiple files

Tags: file, sed, replace, lines

I have thousands of html files in which there are two different pieces of  old google adsense code which needs to be replaced by new ones. The files are on a linux server.

the old code looks like:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-xxx";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
google_ad_format = "336x280_as";
google_ad_type = "text";
//2007-06-09: Forum archive rectangle
google_ad_channel = "1013717472xx";
google_color_border = "FFFFFF";
google_color_bg = "FFFFFF";
google_color_link = "0000FF";
google_color_text = "000000";
google_color_url = "000000";
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

I need to match this text "google_ad_channel = "1013717472xx"" within the code, replace the whole code with new one.

the new code is as follows:

```
<script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pub-config/r20160913/ca-pub-xxx.js"></script><script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pub-config/r20160913/ca-pub-xxx.js"></script><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-xxx";
/* frm arch linkunit 200x90, created 5/30/08 */
google_ad_slot = "0112084554";
google_ad_width = 200;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

How can I use sed to do the replacement in all the html files on my server?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: post your "new code". And what's your OS?

Comment: Thanks. New code added and my OS is ubuntu

Comment: your "new code" does not have any `google_ad_channel ="..."` at all. It's confusing

Comment: the text "google_ad_channel ="..."" is a match term, once it is matched, the whole code is replaced. The new code does not have the term in it.

Comment: install xmlstarlet tool, then tell me when you'll be ready

Answer (score 0):

```
ls |xargs sed -i 's/google_ad_channel = "1013717472xx"/google_ad_channel = "new_code"/g'
```

Comment: Thanks, Mikiya! But I need to replace the whole google adsense code which spans multiple lines, not just the search text.

Comment: @bigbyte , use `sed` with `:label` and `N` can process multiple lines

Comment: Could you put together complete code here? I can do programming in Perl but not shell. Thank you very much!

Comment: @bigbyte , i need a more exact description about the lines to be replaced. Do you mean just `google_ad_channel` is the regex pattern? But what "the whole google adsense code which spans multiple lines" means?

Comment: The code to be replace is the entire "old code" as given in my original post. Since in each of the html files, there are two pieces of google adsense code which differ by channel number, that is why i have to first search by the channel number, then replace one piece of the adsense code.